# Why is my jQuery code failing to match elements with dynamic ids?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

This code is supposed to add a class attribute to the span element "saved" with the right id. but somewhat its not doing so. Perhaps something I am missing, cant seem to figure it out.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(function($){ 

  $("a[id^='savebook-']").click(function(){
    match = this.id.match(/savebook-(\d+)/);
    savedclass = $("span#saved-"+match[1])
    savedclass.addClass("saved");
  });

});
</script>
```

Sample usage

```
<li><span class="save">
   <a href="#" id="savebook-1" rel="nofollow" class="button">Save Book</a>
   <span id="saved-1" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
</span></li>
```

Comment: What I want is <span id="saved-1" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
to be changed to <span id="saved-1" class="saved">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
 
The solution addresses given only addresses the parent

Comment: @kazey: sorry for the confusion - somehow, I missed the third element in your sample. Apart from a few minor issues (Greg points out that you probably want to return false, and you'd also be wise to use local variables), there doesn't appear to be anything wrong with your code...

Comment: Ok I fixed it, Thanks guys the problem was with the span element

Answer (score 2):

You need to `return false;` from the `click()` function to prevent the default action.  Apart from that, it works for me (on Google Chrome).